# Converting for() loops to apply() functions in R for a custom XIRR function

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply, xirr

I've currently been looking for functions to calculate the XIRR of a large database of cashflows/balances in R, and I've come across [this](https://github.com/SunilVeeravalli/XIRR_in_R/blob/master/Xirr%20Code.R) function, which I've been trying to modify to fit my code:

```
library(tidyverse)

xirr2 <- function(exflow, date) {
    if(as.numeric(max(date) - min(date)) <= 2) {
        return(0)
    } else if(abs(sum(exflow, na.rm = TRUE)) < 1e-12) {
        return(0)
    } else {
        npv <- function(range, exflow, date){
            for(test.rate in range) {
                temp <- as.data.frame(cbind(exflow, date)) %>%
                    mutate(npv = exflow * ((1 + test.rate/100)^(as.numeric(max(date) - date)/365))) %>%
                    select(npv) %>%
                    .[1]
                if(sum(exflow, na.rm = TRUE) > 0) {
                    if(sum(temp, na.rm = TRUE) > 0) {
                        min.rate <- test.rate
                        next
                    } else {
                        max.rate <- test.rate
                        break
                    }
                } else {
                    if(sum(temp, na.rm = TRUE) < 0) {
                        min.rate <- test.rate
                        next
                    } else {
                        max.rate <- test.rate
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            return(list(min.rate = min.rate, max.rate = max.rate))
        }
        max.rate <- c()
        min.rate <- c()
        if(sum(exflow, na.rm = TRUE) >= 1e-12) {
            range <- seq(from = 0, to = 1e8, by = 1e3)    
            hundreds <- npv(range, exflow, date)
            range <- seq(from = hundreds$min.rate, to = hundreds$max.rate, by = 10)
            tens <- npv(range, exflow, date)
            range <- seq(from = tens$min.rate, to = tens$max.rate, by = 1)
            ones <- npv(range, exflow, date)
            range <- seq(from = ones$min.rate, to = ones$max.rate, by = 0.01)
            decimals <- npv(range, exflow, date)
            return(mean(unlist(decimals))/100)
        } else {
            range <- seq(from = 0, to = -1e8, by = -1e3)
            hundreds <- npv(range, exflow, date)
            range <- seq(from = hundreds$min.rate, to = hundreds$max.rate, by = -10)
            tens <- npv(range, exflow, date)
            range <- seq(from = tens$min.rate, to = tens$max.rate, by = -1)
            ones <- npv(range, exflow, date)
            range <- seq(from = ones$min.rate, to = ones$max.rate, by = -0.01)
            decimals <- npv(range, exflow, date)
            return(mean(unlist(decimals))/100) 
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, given a vector of cashflows and a vector of corresponding dates, this function returns the annualized XIRR of a investment.

While it works great and generates consistently correct answers when cross-referenced with MS Excel and LibreOffice Calc, it is a bit on the slower side, and I feel that it could be improved by replacing the `for()` loop with an `apply()` function or something from the `data.table` package.  The speed issues are barely noticeable on small examples, but on large datasets like mine with a ton of edge cases, the slow-down can be pretty substantial.

For what it's worth, I've tried a multitude of other XIRR functions from various packages, including `tvm`, `FinancialMath`, and `FinCal`.  For whatever reason, these functions tend to break down over time: solutions eventually stop converging and become inaccurate, particularly with large cashflows and rapid changes between positive/negative returns.  This might possibly be due to a common reliance on the `uniroot()` or `polyroot()` functions in R to calculate XIRR, but I'm not sure.

In any case, the above function actually gets me the numbers I want---I just need some help optimizing it for larger datasets.  Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

Thank you for the help so far.  Here are some minimum examples:

Some deposits, some withdrawals, and then a complete withdrawal for a positive return.  MS Excel shows XIRR = 15.32%:

```
> flow1 <- c(-1000,-100,100,1200)
> date1 <- as.Date(c("2018-01-01","2018-10-31","2019-03-31","2019-03-31"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
> tvm::xirr(flow1,date1)
Error in uniroot(xnpv, interval = interval, cf = cf, d = d, tau = tau,  : 
  f.lower = f(lower) is NA
> xirr2(flow1,date1)
[1] 0.15315
```

An account receiving regular contributions with a poor return.  MS Excel shows XIRR = -27.54%:

```
> flow2 <- c(-200,-200,-200,-200,-200,800)
> date2 <- as.Date(c("2018-01-01","2018-03-01","2018-06-01","2018-09-01","2019-01-01","2019-03-01"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
> tvm::xirr(flow2,date2)
Error in uniroot(xnpv, interval = interval, cf = cf, d = d, tau = tau,  : 
  f.lower = f(lower) is NA
> xirr2(flow2,date2)
[1] -0.27535
```

Maybe I'm just using `tvm::xirr()` wrong?  I'm not sure how to correct that `uniroot()` error.

Comment: "I feel that it could be improved by replacing the for() loop with an apply() function or something from the data.table package." Your feeling is wrong. You need to replace the `for` loop with a vectorized approach or implement it as compiled code with Rcpp. (Also, that unnecessary use of `as.data.frame(cbind())` and dplyr is costing some time. Operations on data.frames are slow. It looks like `temp` should be a matrix.)

Comment: [Profiling R code with the RStudio IDE](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-R-code-with-the-RStudio-IDE#:~:text=The%20profiler%20is%20a%20tool,for%20visualizing%20profiles%20from%20R.) is very handy.

Comment: Noting Roland's comment, also `as.data.frame(cbind(exflow, date))` and `(as.numeric(max(date) - date)/365)` are the same value for every loop iteration, so you could calculate them outside the loop.

Comment: Please post an example dataset with the expected output. This looks like it's basically a very inefficient implementation of `uniroot`. Have you tried the `xirr` function from the `tvm` package--it appears to use `uniroot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71993387/xirr-function-from-tvm-package-delivers-different-outcome-than-xirr-from-excel) answer.  Turns out that `tvm::xirr()` does work well (and is significantly faster than the above function), but I had been calling it incorrectly.  Here is a working example:

```
> flow2 <- c(-200,-200,-200,-200,-200,800)
> date2 <- as.Date(c("2018-01-01","2018-03-01","2018-06-01","2018-09-01","2019-01-01","2019-03-01"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
> tvm::xirr(flow2, date2, comp_freq = 1, maxiter = 100, tol = 1e-8, lower = -0.999, upper = 100)
[1] -0.2753857
```

I had tried this earlier with `lower = -1`, which gives the same error as above.  So I was off by 0.001... so close.  Thank you all again for your help!