Discrepancy between XIRR in R and Excel
I am having an issue slightly similar to this question, I have a quarterly data that the excel and R brings different values e.g. the following in excel =XIRR(I2:I28, B2:B28) brings a value of 2.9802E-09.
In R I am using xirr from the package tvm the following code:
xirr(cf = NCF, d = Date,tau=NULL,comp_freq = Inf) brings a value of -0.664.
I am not really sure what is driving this discrepancy. Can someone please help?
This only arise when the values from Excel XIRR is very small value, but for instance with other examples, the Excel and R values from XIRR are very close to each others.

Are you using the xirr function from tvm or from another package?

For some cash flow patterns, multiple IRRs are valid. What if you put in -0.7 as a guess in Excel?

Perhaps relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71993387/xirr-function-from-tvm-package-delivers-different-outcome-than-xirr-from-excel
